# Distinguish template parameter as a nested template

Tags: c++, templates

I have `getId()` template function, and it can be used like `getId< SomeType >()` and `getId< Some< NestedType >>()`. I have to distinguish them somehow.

```
template<typename TRequest>
ParameterId getId()  // #1
{
    return tEParameterId_None;
}

template<template <class> class TRequest, class TType>
ParameterId getId()  // #2
{
    return TType::paramId;
}

template<TRequest<TType>>
ParameterId getId()  // #3, not working
{
    return TType::paramId;
}

ParameterId none = getId<SomeType>();                   // #1 will be called
ParameterId still_none = getId<Some<NestedType>>();     // #1 will be called, but I want #3
ParameterId some_other = getId<SomeType, NestedType>(); // #2 will be called
```

My question is, how can I specify **#3 `getId()`** template function, that `getId< Some < NestedType > >()` invokes exactly 3d variant? Or which compile-time template magic can I do distinguish nested template?

Because in whole code notation like `Some< NestedType >` is used, and I don't want to change it and invoke like `getId< SomeType, NestedType >()` - it will be inconsistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom type trait to detect if a type is a template :

```
template <class> 
struct is_template : std::false_type {};

template <template <class...> class T, typename ...Args>
struct is_template<T<Args...>> : std::true_type {};
```

And use [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) to select the correct overload (enable an overload if the type is a template, otherwise enable the other) :

```
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<is_template<T>::value, int>::type getId()  // #1
{
    std::cout << "#1";
    return 42;
}

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<!is_template<T>::value, int>::type getId()  // #2
{
    std::cout << "#2";
    return 42;
}
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    getId<int>();               // Calls #2
    getId<std::vector<int>>();  // Calls #1
}
```

**[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/234f5616dcf50a28)**

Answer (score 3):

This will recursively apply your rule, unwinding templates until you get to a non-template parameter:

```
template<class T>
struct param_id : std::integral_constant< int, T::paramId > {};
template<template<class...>class Z, class T, class... Args>
struct param_id<Z<T,Args...>> : param_id<T> {};

template<class T>
constexpr int getId() { return param_id<T>::value; }
```

`constexpr` is optional, but in C++11 means that `getId<SomeType>()` is compile-time evaluated in many contexts.

This means that `getId< std::vector< std::vector< SomeType > > >()` is `getId< SomeType >()`.  It also means that if you want other primitive types to have a fixed id, you can manually specialist `param_id`.

If you want an industrial strength solution, I'd go as far as to create a ADL based lookup scheme, but that is the matter for a more complex answer.

`std::integral_constant` is another C++11ism.  If you lack that support, replace

```
template<class T>
struct param_id : std::integral_constant< int, T::paramId > {};
```

with

```
template<class T>
struct param_id { enum {value=T::paramId}; };
```